# How to write a ndarry to a structure file with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `22` * `25` arrays in numpy `ar`:

```
 0.1   0.0 .....  0.25
 0.2   0.1 .....  0.0
 ...
 0.0   0.01....   0.6
```

And i tried:

```
ar.tofile("f.txt",sep = " ")
```

What i got is a long string, how can I got a file with `22` rows and `25` columns? Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean a CSV or other text file.  'structure file' doesn't mean much; and you aren't dealing with a `structured array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using `np.savetext()`:

```
np.savetxt('f.txt', ar, fmt='%.2f')
```